# ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /127.0.0.1:9042

Tags: configuration, cassandra

I am trying to insert values in cassandra when I come across this error:

```
15/08/14 10:21:54 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /a.b.c.d:9042 added
15/08/14 10:21:54 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
15/08/14 10:21:54 ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /127.0.0.1:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:109)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:32)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:586)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SingleConnectionPool.<init>(SingleConnectionPool.java:76)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.newInstance(HostConnectionPool.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:271)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:40)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:308)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042
```

My replication factor is 1. There are 5 nodes in the Cass cluster (they're all up). rpc_address: 0.0.0.0, broadcast_rpc_address: 127.0.0.1

I would think that I should see 5 of those "INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host.." line from above for each of the 5 nodes. **But instead I see 127.0.0.1, I am not sure why.**

I also noticed that in the cassandra.yaml file, all the 5 nodes are listed under seed. (which I know is not advised but I did not set up this  cluster)

```
seed_provider:
class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
parameters:
seeds: "ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5"
```

Where ipx is the ipaddr for node x.

And under cassandra-topology.properties it just says the following and does not mention any of the 5 nodes.

```
# default for unknown nodes                                                                                                                     

default=DC1:r1
```

Can someone explain why I am seeing the ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /127.0.0.1:9042 error.

Kind of new to Cassandra.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Why 30418?  The typical port Cassandra listens on is 9042.

Comment: @rs_atl That is for firewall reasons but I know thats not what is causing the problem. I've changed it to 9042 so it doesn't cause any confusion. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is your rpc_broadcast_address is set to 127.0.0.1.  Is there a reason in particular you are doing this?

The java driver uses the system.peers table to look up the ip address to use to connect to hosts.  If rpc_broadcast_address is set this is what will be present in system.peers and the driver will try to use it.  If rpc_broadcast_address is not set, rpc_address will be used.  In either case, you'll want to set one of these addresses to an address that will be accessible by your client.  If you set rpc_address, you will want to remove broadcast_rpc_address.

Comment: If `rpc_address` is set to 0.0.0.0, `broadcast_rpc_address` must be set. But it should be set to the address you expect clients to connect to, not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @AndyTolbert I see what you're saying. I will change the broadcast_rpc_address and see what it does. But I am still confused about why I see 127.0.0.1 being added as New Cassandra host. I would think that all the other nodes configured as a part of Cassandra cluster (that are usually mentioned in "cassandra-topology.properties) be added as New Cassandra host. Why is 127.0.0.1 one of these?

Comment: `broadcast_rpc_address` is what Cassandra sends to the driver, and what the driver uses to uniquely identify hosts. The addresses in `cassandra-topology.properties` are what Cassandra nodes use to communicate between each other. The driver knows nothing about these addresses (they might even be on a private network, that the client has no access to).