# Apache Spark Error creating pool to EC2 Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

My configuration are:
1 Spark machine on EC2: c3.2xlarge.
Communicating with 4 nodes of Cassandra on EC2.

I am getting the following error:

`16/08/03 22:41:10 ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /XX.XX.XXX.XX:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/XX.XX.XXX.XX:9042] Cannot connect`

The XX are the public IP of the EC2 cassandra.
However inside my spark configuration: Im telling spark to use the seeder internal IP node, which then the spark-connector driver receive the information from Cassandra the public IP.

How my IT set the clusters up, I am assuming the following:
[ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /127.0.0.1:9042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012777/error-session-error-creating-pool-to-127-0-0-19042)

However I don't want to have my clusters connect via public IP and open up the firewall. I would like to have it stay to the internal IP of the cluster.

Is there a way to do this Spark code level wise or cassandra.yml configuration wise?

Comment: Is this port 9042 allowing access to the Spark Machine? Try checking using Telnet from the Spark Machine to the node?

Comment: @error2007s as i mentioned,  its firewalled from the outside. Internal IP passes through. as mentioned I dont want to open up the outside firewall. So 9042 is open for internal IP